# How to loop a function with a value from that same function?

Tags: python, function

I am currently in the process of creating a "hangman" game. Below is a function I have developed that returns the unused letters. However I am not sure how to save the value I receive from the function and use it again when it loops in in the while loop...

This is what it is currently doing.

HELLO (word)

L (guessed letter)
Unused letters: ABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

A (guessed letter)
Unused letters: BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

O (guessed letter)
Unused letters: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ

I need it to do this instead. Notice how it keeps the changes from the previous string/list.

L (guessed letter)
Unused letters: ABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

A (guessed letter)
Unused letters: BCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

O (guessed letter)
Unused letters: BCDEFGHIJKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ

```
ALPHABET = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R','S', 'T', 'U','V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

word = input() #word player 2 is trying to guess
guessedletter = input()


def correctguess(): #Prints unused letters
    newABC = []
    newABCstring = ('')
    for x in ALPHABET:
        if x != guessedletter:
            newABC.append(x)
            newABCstring = (newABCstring + str(x))
    print("Unused letters:" + " " + (newABCstring))
   

guesses=6
while guesses<=6 and guesses>0:
    correctguess()
    guessedletter=input()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of the unused letters in a global variable. I don't fully follow your code, but it could like something like this:

```py
ALPHABET = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R','S', 'T', 'U','V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

word = input() #word player 2 is trying to guess
guessedletter = input()

unused = ALPHABET

def correctguess(): #Prints unused letters
    for x in ALPHABET:
        if x == guessedletter:
            unused.remove(x)
    print("Unused letters:", "".join(unused))
   

guesses=6
while guesses<=6 and guesses>0:
    correctguess()
    guessedletter=input()
```

Answer (score 0):

What this problem is asking for is a global variable to keep track of used letters (or, alternatively, unused letters).

You should declare this variable outside of function. Initialize it at the start of the program (either to full alphabet or to empty list), then update it every time you get input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

You should use another variable to keep track of your unused letters. This should work to remove each letter from your list.

```
ALPHABET = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R','S', 'T', 'U','V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

word = input() #word player 2 is trying to guess
try:
     guessedletter = input() #this will need somesort of loop around it for the game to continue as well
     RemainingLetters.Contains(guessedletter)
     correctguess(guessedletter)
catch:
     print("You have already used that letter")

RemainingLetters = ALPHABET

def correctguess(x): #Prints unused letters (x is used to get the letter that got guessed

    RemainingLetters.Remove(RemainingLetters.Index(x)) #find the index of the guessed letter and removes it
    print("Unused letters: " + RemainingLetters))
```